# How to copy large datatable to MySql table?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datatable

I am trying to copy a large datatable (columns with more than 1000 rows) created dynamically in the applicaiton to a MySQL table using c#, WPF. 
I have searched for various ways to do this but was unsuccessful to implement. I think the MySqlDataAdapter class is something I should use but I cant make it work. This is what I tried to do...

```
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("Select * From kinectdata", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter test1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(comm);
        test1.Update(skelData);
```

Speed of this transfer is also important so I prefered not to call an insert or update statement 1000 times.

Many thanks for your feedback! 
M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a single `INSERT` statement which inserts all 1000 rows.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9);
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I tried the data adapter and command builder but the straight up one line command was much faster.

Comment: @Keith is this insert statement limited by size? i can't imagine you're able to insert a GB of data that way

Comment: @fubo: yes, there is probably SQL byte limit.  And you probably don't want to use all of the DB memory to hold one statement anyway.  Chunk your data into groups with a reasonable insert size (<64KB?) and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Keith: thanks for response. i guess you're right. i've tried to insert about 5MB and it worked without any issues - but it took a while :). what a pitty, mysql has no solution with parameters for this case.

Answer (score 3):

1000 rows is not that much, in database terms its nothing, using insert should be very fast. No more then 2 seconds.

In your example you do have to declare command type and set your query and command text.